# database solution for multiple isolated graphs

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have an interesting problem that I don't know how to solve.
I have collected a large dataset of 80 million graphs (they are CFG as in Control Flow Graph produced by programs I have analysed from Github) which I need to be able to search efficiently.
I looked into existing solutions like Neo4j but they are all designed to store a global single graph.
In my case this is the opposite all graphs are independent  -like rows in a table - but I need to search through all of them efficiently.
For example I want to find all CFGs that has a particular IF condition or a WHILE loop with a particular condition.
What's the best database for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there's a reason not to simply store all those graphs in a single graph, whether it's Neo4j or a different graph database. It's not a problem to have many disparate graphs in a single graph where the disparate graphs are disconnected from one another.

As for searching them efficiently, you would either (1) identify properties in your CFGs that you want to search on and convert them to some indexed value of the graph or (2) introduce some graph structure (additional vertices/edges) between the CFGs that will allow you to do the searches you want via graph traversal.

Depending on what you need to search on approach 1 may not be flexible enough for you especially, if what you intend to search on is not completely known at the time of loading the data. Also, it is important to note that with approach 2 you do not really lose the fact that you have 80 million distinct graphs just because you provided some connection between them. Those physical connections don't change that basic logical fact. You just need to consider those additional connections when you write traversals that you expect to occur only within a single CFG.

I'm not sure what Neo4j supports in this area, but with [Apache TinkerPop](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/) (an open source graph processing framework that lets you write vendor agnostic code over different graph databases, including Neo4j), you might consider doing some form of [graph partitioning](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_partitionstrategy) to help with approach 2. Or you might [subgraph()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#subgraph-step) the larger graph to only contain the CFG and then operate with that purely in memory when querying. Both of these approaches will help you to blind your query to just the individual CFG you want to traverse.

Ultimately, however, I see this issue as a modelling problem. You will just need to make some choices on how to best establish the schema for your use case and virtually any graph database should be able to support that.

Comment: Hello stephen, thanks for the pointers. What format would you use to store the graph before I load them into the graph database? I use a classical data lake solution based on S3 where I will store the raw output of the CFG parser and then do an ETL step to load them. What's the best format to serialize them?

Comment: Any reason not to store the raw output of the CFG parser and then later have a second step to just read the CFG format directly into the graph database? Also, with 80 million of those files you might want to consider parallel loading that data. If you used TinkerPop, that might mean loading the data with http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#bulkloadervertexprogram over Spark.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, the TinkerPop bulk import seems to be what I was looking for thanks!